# How to have map_from_arrays() in Spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following Dataframe in Spark 2.3, coming from a JSON file:

```
root
 |-- ext_attr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I would need to convert it to below DataFrame:

```
root
 |-- ext_attr_map: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

I saw that in Spark 2.4 probably the map_from_arrays() would do that.

How can I achieve this in Spark 2.3 ? Please provide a UDF or SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val df1 = Seq(Seq(("1","a1"),("2","a2")),Seq(("3","a3"),("4","a4"))).toDF()
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>>]

scala> df1.printSchema
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)


scala> df1.select('*,monotonically_increasing_id.as("id")).select('id,explode('value)).select('id,map($"col._1",$"col._2").as("value")).groupBy('id).agg(collect_list('value).as("value")).select('value).printSchema
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

    enter code here
```